# Hibernate Select data : Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i'm getting this error when i try to select data for my  @OneToMany relationship,
this is my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@DynamicInsert

public class Person
    implements java.io.Serializable
{

//properties ....

private Set<Adress> adresses = new HashSet<Adress>( 0 );

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    public Set<Adress> getAdresses()
    {
        return this.adresses;
    }

    public void setAdresses( Set<Adress> adresses )
    {
        this.adresses = adresses;
    }

}

//Adress class

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADRESS")
public class Adress
    implements java.io.Serializable
{

//properties ....

private Person person;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PERSON")
    public Constat getPerson()
    {
        return this.person;
    }

    public void setPerson( Person person )
    {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

when i try to get one Adress object i get the error , this is my service :

```
  public Adress findLastAdressByType( String noPerson, String type )
    {
        List<Adress> result = getHibernateTemplate().find( "from Adress as Adress where Adress.person.noPerson = ? and Adress.type = ? order by dateCreation desc ", noPerson, type );
        if ( !result.isEmpty() )
        {
            return result.get( 0 );
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and this my getHibernateTemplate().find() service :

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> find( String queryString, Object... values )
        throws DataAccessException
    {
        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery( queryString );
        for ( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ )
        {
            query.setParameter( i, values[i] );
        }
        return query.list();
    }
```

i get the error "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1" in the ligne :

```
 return query.list();
```

and

```
List<Adress> result = getHibernateTemplate().find( "from Adress as Adress where Adress.person.noPerson = ? and Adress.type = ? order by dateCreation desc ", noPerson, type );
```

:

can anyone help me to know what is exactly the problem , is this a problem with hibernate or i have a problem in my relation annotation.

Regards !

Comment: You must may be use `Adress.dateCreation ` in your query, and add a space to the beginning of your query.

Comment: @RayLloy thank you for your response, but why you think that dateCreation  without Adress alias may cause the problem ?! Regards

Comment: beacause you have use all the other fields with the Adress alias. And further more I think if you don't specify alias, the field will be unknown. And what is returned by the method `getHibernateTemplate()` ?

Comment: but what i'm thinkg is that hibernate try to update the object before select it , it's right ?!

Comment: I think so but this is so strange. Can you set your hibernate.show_sql to true and post your query please ?

Comment: Hibernate: update ADRESS set NO_ADRESS=?, DATE_CREATION=?,NO_CONSTAT=? EXTENSION=?, NOM=?, , TYPE=? where NO_PIECE_JOINTE=?

select adress0_.NO_ADRESS as NO1_5_, adress0_.NO_CONSTAT as NO12_5_, adress0_.DATE_CREATION as NO13_5_ from ADRESS adress0_ where 
adress0_.NO_CONSTAT=? and adress0_.TYPE=?  order by adress0_.DATE_CREATION desc

Comment: Hibernate make update before select and i don't know why  :(

Comment: I have find this may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958552/hibernate-executes-update-on-select-call) can help you.